# Why is the hot reload button not showing up?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

I've seen a bunch of tutorials on Youtube where they just run a ASP.NET template project, and the hot reload button shows up next to the 'Start Without Debugging' button on the top panel. I do not know why this is not happening for me, the button is just not there. I installed VS 2022 just recently (in mid-July 2022) and the project is using .NET 6. What should I do?

[image: VS 2022 F# project toolbar]

Comment: Maybe the hot reload feature is C# only? It shows up in a C# project, but not in the F# project.

Comment: I fixed this issue by opening the `sln` file instead of the `csproj` file. But I have minimal knowledge about the meaning of these files - maybe your issue is a similar config issue. You could try creating the project from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [you mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048719/why-is-the-hot-reload-button-not-showing-up/73053803#comment129021339_73048719), F# does not support Hot Reloading according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022#unsupported-net-scenarios) (I am guessing you are working in an F# project by the sounds of it).  Here are the unsupported scenarios:

> - Xamarin.Forms apps won’t support .NET Hot Reload in iOS and Android scenarios. You get partial support for Hot Reload when targeting a UWP app. This is by design, and we don’t expect to make any further improvements. (Note: XAML Hot Reload will continue to be available and supported for Xamarin.Forms customers on the latest SDK.)
> - .NET MAUI apps are not supported prior to Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1 Preview 1. Starting in 17.1 Preview 1, .NET MAUI is supported, but only with the debugger attached.
> - Apps built using F# or those targeting .NET Native do not support Hot Reload.

Aside from that, if you still don't see the icon, check your toolbar settings.

Comment: Hmm, it says that it does not support .NET Native apps with F#. But is the ASP.NET project really a .NET Native one?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinić can you add a screenshot of your toolbar to your post? An ASP.NET project should really have Hot Reload available - my ASP.NET Web API project has it (it uses .NET Framework).

Comment: Done. As I said, it does not show up in the F# project, but the flame icon is there in a C# one. I am don't know if it doesn't shows up in regular F# projects, so far I've only tried an ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2022.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinić Interestingly, if I create a new F# project (console app), the hot reload is not in the toolbar.  But if I add to the solution a .NET Core C# Web API project, the icon appears.  But I expect it will work with the Web API project only.